# How do I logout with JWT, passport Authentication (NodeJS)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt

I am new to NodeJS and I have been following a tutorial. I made some changes to the tutorial code in order to allow users to login by typing in their username or email instead of just username.

```
passport.use(
  new LocalStrategy(
    (username_or_email, password, done) => {
      User.findOne({ email: username_or_email }, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
          return done(err);
          console.log(err);
        }
        if (!user) {
          User.findOne({ username: username_or_email }, (err, user) => {
            //If there is an error
            if (err) {
              return done(err);
              console.log(err);
            }
            //If there is no user
            if (!user) {
              return done(null, false);
            } else {
              user.comparePassword(password, done);
            }
          });
        } else {
          user.comparePassword(password, done);
        }
      });
    }
  )
```

The code above works well and allows users to type in username OR password to login.

Now when I follow the tutorial for how to logout, their method doesn't work for me.

**I have a route like this, it is supposed to log a user out.**

```
userRouter.get(
      '/logout',
      passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),
      (req, res) => {
        res.clearCookie('access_token');
        res.json({ user: { username: '', role: '' }, success: true });
      }
    );
```

When I go to it in Postman it says "Unauthorized" and does not return anything else.
I believe it could be something to do with my 'jwt' set up, shown below.

```
passport.use(
  new JwtStrategy(
    {
      jwtFromRequest: cookieExtractor,
      secretOrKey: 'NoobCoder',
    },
    (payload, done) => {
      console.log(payload);
      User.findById({ _id: payload.sub }, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
          return done(err, false);
          console.log('1');
        }
        if (user) {
          return done(null, user);
          console.log('2');
        } else {
          return done(null, false);
          console.log('3');
        }
      });
    }
  )
);
```

**This is the cookieExtractor function that I use for jwtFromRequest**

```
const cookieExtractor = (req) => {
  let token = null;
  console.log(token);
  if (req && req.cookies) {
    token = req.cookies['access_token'];
  }
  return token;
};
```

The only console output I get is the console.log in the cookieExtractor.
Which makes me believe that that must be the point of failure. It is a "null" output as expected, and if I console.log the token, I get the current logged in users token. I believe the jwtFromRequest calls the cookieExtractor function but fails at some point soon after.

Comment: passport exposes a logout function, you could try it: [passport logout](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/logout/)

Comment: @buzatto it doesn't log you out if your user info is stored on a JWT token. An ideal solution would be to send the token through the /logout api and expiring it.